# Can't send correct data with view in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a easy booking system in codeIgniter and using a database with a table called conference_rooms. I'm calling for this in my `Booking_Model.php`like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_room() {

    $query = $this->db->get('conference_rooms');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

}

To display it I'm using my `Booking.php` class looking like this:

```
public function view()
{
    $data['conference_rooms'] = $this->booking_model->get_room();

    if (empty($data['conference_rooms'])) {

        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['conference_rooms']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And my `view.php`:

```
<h3><?php echo $conference_rooms['title']; ?></h3>
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $conference_rooms['seats']; ?>
</div>
```

It won't find `$room`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Basically changed the whole code, my view class now looks like this (changed to index in my Booking controller)

```
    public function index() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');

    $this->load->model('Booking_Model');
    $rooms = $this->Booking_Model->get();
    $rooms_form_options = array();

    foreach ($rooms as $id => $room) {
        $rooms_form_options[$id] = $room->title;
    }

    $this->load->model('Package_Model');
    $packages = $this->Package_Model->get();
    $packages_form_options = array();

    foreach ($packages as $id => $package) {
        $packages_form_options[$id] = $package->package_name;
    }

    $this->load->view('booking', array(
        'rooms_form_options' => $rooms_form_options,
        'packages_form_options' => $packages_form_options,
    ));


    $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');

}
```

And my `booking.php`;

```
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Conference Room', 'id') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('id', $rooms_form_options, set_value('id')); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Package type', 'package_id') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('package_id', $packages_form_options, set_value('package_id')); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo form_label('Antal deltagare', 'number_people') ; ?>
    <?php echo form_input('number_people', set_value('number_people')) ; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <?php echo form_submit('preview', 'Book'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you loaded model in controller file like `$this->load->model('booking_Model', '', TRUE);`?

Comment: Where are you setting the variables for title and seats inside the $conference_rooms Array

Comment: I've loaded it like `$this->load->model('news_model');`  and it works, because I forgot about in the beginning and got an error message for it that's gone now

Comment: I guess no where, so that might be the problem? How do I do it? @Amit

Comment: Have you check `$this->booking_model->get_room()` returns the result or not?

Comment: If you define `$data['title']` then in the view you have to write `echo $title`; not like `echo $conference_rooms['title']`.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it with the answers below?

Comment: @teninchhero have you check the answer???

Comment: none of the below answers worked so maybe its the `$this->booking_model->get_room()` that doesn't return anything?

Comment: @teninchhero we are also provided you if `$this->booking_model->get_room()` does't return any thing it will return your 404 page

Comment: Ok, I don't get 404 page but an error so then it must work. Can it be my router?

Comment: @teninchhero you said that `conference_rooms` is your database. Use the table name instead.

Comment: @Scorpion Sorry, my bad I meant the name of the table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

In Model

```
<?
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function get_room() {

        $query = $this->db->get('conference_rooms');
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

In controller

```
    function view()
    {
        $data['conference_rooms'] = $this->booking_model->get_room();

        if (empty($data['conference_rooms']))
        {

            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

    }
?>
```

in view

```
<h3><?php echo $conference_rooms[0]['title']; ?></h3>
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $conference_rooms[0]['seats']; ?>
</div>
```

cz of `$conference_rooms[0]` pointing 0 is we passing data with Objective array. so we need to point data. check with `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

**MODEL**

You need to   [`row_array();`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=row_array#CI_DB_result::row_array) to return an `array`

```
public function get_room() {
    $query = $this->db->get('conference_rooms');
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();

    if( $rowcount > 0 ){
        return $row = $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function view()
{
    $conference_rooms = $this->booking_model->get_room();// asing your array to variable

    if (empty($conference_rooms)) {

        show_404();

    } else {

        $data['conference_rooms']=$conference_rooms;// pass your variable to data array to pass into view

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<h3><?php echo $conference_rooms['title']; ?></h3>
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $conference_rooms['seats']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work, it can't find `$conference_rooms`. Thinking that @ Kausha Mehta can be right and that the `get_room` doesn't work. How do I check that?

Comment: `print_r( $conference_rooms)` in controller and paste the value of it!!

Comment: _Message: Undefined variable: conference_rooms_

Comment: Can it have something to do with the router?

Comment: check updated answer for removing `Undefined variable: conference_rooms` for model file use `num_rows()`

Comment: Same thing. How should my router be looking?